# question on transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation, coordinate-systems

If a $2$d coordinate transformation function is given by $f(x,y)= 3x+1$, then what does it mean? How do I calculate the transformed coordinates for the points say $(3,4)$ in the initial space?

Comment: why is your function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$? In other words, your "transformation" function, can't take inputs of $y$.

Comment: Usually transformation functions are like u=$x^2 - y^2$ and $v=x*y$, where $(u,v)$ are transformed coordinates and $(x,y)$ are initial coordinates. I was reading about non-linear transformations, where i came across the above function.

Comment: Ok what will be the coordinates if it was $f(x,y) = 3x+7y$

Comment: $f(x,y)$ is your transformation? Do you just want to map any points from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to f(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes. $f(x,y)$ is the transformation function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take points on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and map them or transform them to $f(x,y)=3x+7y$, this doesn't really define a transformation, without more addtional information. Essentially from what I've gathered, you just want to map the set of all points in $\mathbb{R}^2\to f(x,y)$. This just defines a multivariable function.

So you're in a sense transforming the plane of all pairs of points in the $xy$-plane to the function you defined. If you want to see what happens at a given point, just plug in the $x$ and $y$ values.

For example $(2,3)$:

$f(2,3)=3(2)+7(3)=6+21=27$.

But also if you just want $f(x,y)=3x+1$ this defines an infinite number of lines, since it does not depend on $y$. You can graph these lines on paper and see what happens.

Comment: Yes it is clear. It is actually not a transformation function then? I mean I cannot have new coordinates getting mapped for older coordinates using these type of equations?

Comment: It is technically a transformation, but it isn't doing much more than if you say that $f(x)=x+1$ is a transformation of the real numbers. It's just a line. But you were saying stuff about $u$ and $v$ being represented by $x$ and $y$, these are a change of coordinates. While this is not.

Comment: Awesome :) thanks @MITjanitor. I can't vote up your answer because I dont have enough reputation.Your answer is perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Chetan: don't worry, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x,y) \equiv 3x+1$, then $f(3, 4) = f(3, y) = 10$. $f(x,y)$ is not dependent to y. The $10$ value is also for $f(3, 0) = f(3, -10) = f(3, 2e45) = \cdots = 10$ and so on.